# Multiprocessing using shared memory

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Can someone provide me with sample code to share a writable array or a list among a pool of worker processes or even individually spawned processes using the multiprocessing module of python using locks? My code below spawns 2 processes of which one should print '1' and the other should print '2' to the shared array. However, when I try to print out the elements of the array after the processing it only gives me a list of 0's. Where am I going wrong? I want a writable data structure to be shared between multiple processes.

Below is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

arr=multiprocessing.Array('i',10,lock=True)
lock=multiprocessing.RLock()

def putitin(n):
    for i in range(5):
        lock.acquire()
        arr.append(n)
        lock.release()
    return

p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin,args=(1,))
p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin,args=(2,))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

for i in range(10):
    print(arr[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential problem with your code is that to use `multiprocessing` on Windows you need to put the code for the main process in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. See the **Safe importing of main module** subsection of the [Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) section of the [*multiprocessing Programming guidelines*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

Another major one is that you're attempting to a share global variable among the processes. which won't work because each one runs in its own unshared memory-space, so each subprocess has its own `arr`. (Variables which are just module level constants are OK, though)

Lastly, a `multiprocessing.Array` has a fixed size and doesn't have the `extend()` method your code is trying to use in the `putitin()` function — therefore it appears you also want a writable *and* resizable container (that is ordered and perhaps accessible via integer indices).

In that case something the like the following may be suitable. You don't need to explicitly lock the object before making changes to it because it's a thread-safe shared object.

```
import multiprocessing

def putitin(lst, value):
    for i in range(5):
        lst.append(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lst = manager.list()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin, args=(lst, 1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin, args=(lst, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        print(lst[i])
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: This is a just a simple piece of code. I have a method which runs 1000 monte carlo simulations but instead of executing those simulations serially, I want them to run in parallel by having the simulations run by 5 processes (so 200 simulations per process). I want each process to write the results to one common array (of size 1000). And since locks are the best way to share resources, my question is how to i acquire a lock on the array when one process is writing to it?

Comment: Also for every single process, I want it to acquire a lock on the shared array as soon as its done processing the results as opposed to diving the array into seperate segments for each process

Comment: Vedant7: Not sure I understand. Regardless, you can get the lock for the entire shared array whenever you need it by using a `lock = arr.get_lock()` (or better yet, acquire it using a `with arr.get_lock(): ...` block. See [_Shared `ctypes` Objects_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects). Also note it should be an `RLock` in that case.

Comment: It does not exactly solve my problem because I donot want to divide the array into small segments reserved for each process.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you want better now. See update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues that I found in your code. First of all, it [seems to be a good idea](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) to pass all shared resources to child and use `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Secondly, I don't think `multiprocessing.Array` has `append()` method (at least it didn't work for me on Python2 and Python3). Thirdly, since you are using `lock=True` I don't think you need additional locks.

If you need to append values to the Array I'd use separate Counter variable (see the code below).

```
import multiprocessing


def putitin(n, arr, counter):
        for i in range(5):
            with counter.get_lock():
                index = counter.value
                counter.value += 1
            arr[index] = n

if __name__ == '__main__':
        arr = multiprocessing.Array('i', 10,lock=True)
        counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=True)
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin,args=(1, arr, counter))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=putitin,args=(2, arr, counter))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        p2.join()
        p1.join()

        for i in range(10):
            print(arr[i])
```

Having said that, what is your high-level goal? What are you trying to achieve with it? Maybe it's possible to use `multiprocessing.Pool`?